# Profiler in C#?

Tags: c#, profiler

Currently to performance test code that I write, I have to create some sort of separate throw away executable and set up the timing manually. I really like how the unit testing is built into VS so that I don't have to write a separate executable to get information. Is there anything similar for performance testing? If not, does anyone know of a good performance testing framework so that I can stop writing throw away testing executables? I'm not finding anything on Google that seems appropriate for C#. Thanks.

EDIT: I guess I'm looking for something like [this](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/benchmark.html), only maintained

Answer (score 3):

[EQATEC](http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler) has some good tools for just this that are FREE. There are metrics of time spent in each method call, memory consumption, etc... Really useful information in detailing exactly where your performance bottlenecks are.

If you have the money for it, [dotTRACE](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) is really good as well. dotTRACE is essentially the same thing, just presented in a much more friendly and intuitive fashion.

Comment: +1 - EQATEC Profiler is very basic, but it works. We've used it on several projects. JetBrains does offer memory profiling (among other features) in dotTrace, though, which EQATEC Profiler does not support.

Answer (score 1):

It's built in to Visual Studio: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9z62c29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for perfmon

and see this link

http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2008/04/03/using-perfmon-to-tune-n-tier-net-applications/